# keras-tensorflow CAE dimension mismatch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm basically following [this](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) guide to build convolutional autoencoder with tensorflow backend. The main difference to the guide is that my data is 257x257 grayscale images. The following code:

```
TRAIN_FOLDER = 'data/OIRDS_gray/'
EPOCHS = 10
SHAPE = (257,257,1)

FILELIST = os.listdir(TRAIN_FOLDER)

def loadTrainData():
    train_data = []
    for fn in FILELIST:
        img = misc.imread(TRAIN_FOLDER + fn)
        img = np.reshape(img,(len(img[0,:]), len(img[:,0]), SHAPE[2]))
        if img.shape != SHAPE:
            print "image shape mismatch!"
            print "Expected: " 
            print SHAPE 
            print "but got:"
            print img.shape
            sys.exit()
        train_data.append (img)
    train_data = np.array(train_data)
    train_data = train_data.astype('float32')/ 255

    return np.array(train_data)

def createModel():
    input_img = Input(shape=SHAPE)
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)  
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid',padding='same')(x)
    return Model(input_img, decoded)


x_train = loadTrainData()
autoencoder = createModel()
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

print x_train.shape
autoencoder.summary()

# Run the network
autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=EPOCHS,
                batch_size=128,
                shuffle=True)
```

gives me a error:
`ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_7 to have shape (None, 260, 260, 1) but got array with shape (859, 257, 257, 1)`

As you can see this is not the standard problem with theano/tensorflow backend dim ordering, but something else. I checked that my data is what it's supposed to be with `print x_train.shape`:

```
(859, 257, 257, 1)
```

And I also run `autoencoder.summary()`:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 257, 257, 1)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 257, 257, 16)      160
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 129, 129, 16)      0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 129, 129, 8)       1160
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 65, 65, 8)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 65, 65, 8)         584
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 33, 33, 8)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 33, 33, 8)         584
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2 (None, 66, 66, 8)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 66, 66, 8)         584
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2 (None, 132, 132, 8)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 132, 132, 16)      1168
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling2 (None, 264, 264, 16)      0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 264, 264, 1)       145
=================================================================
Total params: 4,385
Trainable params: 4,385
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Now I'm not exactly sure where the problem is, but it does look like things go wrong around conv2d_6 (Param # too high). I do know how CAE's work on principle, but I'm not that familiar with the exact technical details yet and I have tried to solve this mainly by messing with deconvolution padding (instead of same, using valid). The closes I got to dims matching was `(None, 258, 258, 1)`. I achieved this by blindly trying different combinations of padding on deconvolution side, not really a smart way to solve a problem...

At this point I'm at a loss, and any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your input and output data are the same, your final output shape should be the same as the input shape.

The last convolutional layer should have shape `(None, 257,257,1)`.

The problem is happening because you have an odd number as the sizes of the images (257).

When you apply `MaxPooling`, it should divide the number by two, so it chooses rounding either up or down (it's going up, see the 129, coming from 257/2 = 128.5)

Later, when you do `UpSampling`, the model doesn't know the current dimensions were rounded, it simply doubles the value. This happening in sequence is adding 7 pixels to the final result.

You could try either cropping the result or padding the input.

I usually work with images of compatible sizes. If you have 3 `MaxPooling` layers, your size should be a multiple of 2³. The answer is 264.

---

**Padding the input data directly:**

```
x_train = numpy.lib.pad(x_train,((0,0),(3,4),(3,4),(0,0)),mode='constant')
```

This will require that `SHAPE=(264,264,1)`

**Padding inside the model:**

```
import keras.backend as K

input_img = Input(shape=SHAPE)
x = Lambda(lambda x: K.spatial_2d_padding(x, padding=((3, 4), (3, 4))), output_shape=(264,264,1))(input_img)
```

**Cropping the results:**

This will be required in any case where you do not change the actual data (numpy array) directly.

```
decoded = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,3:-4,3:-4,:], output_shape=SHAPE)(x)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this cleared up any problems I had. Would have taken some time for me to realize on my own by manually debugging, though quite clear in hindsight.